# Delphi DCEF3 - Change locale

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I want to change the DCEF3 (Delphi Chromium Embedded 3) to display local data (like time and dates) in my language, Norwegian. Now it defaults to English.

I see that the source code has an own "locales" folder (https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/#git%2Fbin%2FWin32%2Flocales). How do I tell the chromium component to use nb.pak?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the [`CefLocale`](https://code.google.com/p/dcef3/source/browse/src/ceflib.pas#7903) variable to the name of the locale of your choice (which is the name of the locale file without extension). Do that before the first instance of `TChromium` is created. For instance, if you are having a `TChromium` component dropped on a form, do that from the form's [`OnCreate`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnCreate) event:

```
uses
  ceflib;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CefLocale := 'nb';
end;
```

If you keep this variable empty (which is its default value), the `en-US` locale will be used.